# AWS CloudHSM Private Key retrieval

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pkcs#11, amazon-cloudhsm

I'm trying to retrieve private key from AWS Cloud HSM using PKCS11 Client SDK 5. There's no issue with the connection, but I'm getting an empty list.

Steps taken:

- I have used the following command to produce an ECC key pair:

  ```
  key generate-asymmetric-pair ec \
    --curve secp256r1 \
    --public-label mylabel \
    --private-label mylabel
  ```
- Using PKCS11 Client SDK5
- Logged in to HSM as Crypto User
- Opened a Session
- When fetching the private key using this command:

  ```
  private_key = session.findObjects([(CKA_LABEL , key_label),(CKA_CLASS , CKO_PRIVATE_KEY)])[0]
  ```

  The private key retrieval attempt returns `'[]'`, indicating that there is nothing in the list.

What am I missing here?